# Why to use MPI_Wait in MPI_Send?

Tags: mpi

I would like to understand why should I use MPI_Wait to wait for an MPI request to complete?

So, in the end of MPI_Send scope I would use the MPI_Wait method, but why? 
In my comprehension MPI_Send just send a message and doesn't wait a request to complete, but
the MPI_ISend do!

Thanks.

Comment: It's the opposite: `MPI_Wait` and other similar functions are used to wait and ensure that asynchronous operations like `MPI_Isend` complete. `MPI_Send` is a blocking call - it does not return control back until the operation has completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarize what @Hristo Iliev said, you shouldn't (and can't) call `MPI_WAIT` for a call to `MPI_SEND`. Calling `MPI_WAIT` requires that you pass in an `MPI_Request` object which you get as a return value from an `MPI_I<something>` function. Without that object, MPI doesn't know what you're trying to wait on.

So your reasoning in the end is correct. You don't wait on an `MPI_SEND`, but you do (and must) wait on an `MPI_ISEND`.

Comment: Thanks. But, what should I wait in a MPI_Send request? Should I wait the MPI_Recv send a MPI_Status?

Comment: You don't wait for an MPI_Send request. Once the MPI_Send call has returned, it's done for the purposes of the sending process. At some point in the future, it will be received by the receiving process in an appropriate call.